# Bunkers to save humanity?

Tags: space, asteroids

lets say governments have secretly known about this in advance and have been building these bunkers in secret, including underground farming using artificial light and recycled water

I just want to know how deep these bunkers would have to be and how big they'd need to be to house about 150.000 people

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have know what in advance? How deep they have to be for what?

Comment: Yes, which apocalypse are we designing these bunkers for? I suspect each apocalypse, from Noah-level floods, to astroid impact, plague, and nuclear war will look different.

Comment: @Gillgamesh the tags say "asteroids", though that's not really quite enough to be going on...

Comment: Getting into the details from the previous comments - are the bunkers being (stupidly) built directly under the anticipated impact zone of the asteroid/s?  How big and numerous are the asteroid/s? (ie what is the apocalypse mechanism?)  As for how big the bunkers have to be - how long do they need to support 150,000 people?  Without the details the question is unanswerable and is on the way to being closed.